# Custom authentication for firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to know how I can use my custom authentication for firebase. 
Just want to know even if there is a rest api to change the user data or insert user data into firebase databases.

Sorry if the question is too vague.

Thanks

Comment: Tell us more about your custom authentication method for better support. And yes there is a rest api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot sign in a user through the Firebase REST API.

For custom authentication you need to handle sign-in of the user yourself and then you will need to [mint custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_sdk) on your own app server and pass it back to the client.

The client can then use the custom token to [authenticate with the Firebase Database through its REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#auth) by passing it into the `auth` parameter.